# How do I write an object to a file and read it back without using json and pickling in python?

Tags: python-3.x, object, text-files, readfile, writefile

I created a class called Hand and an object h1. I wrote the result of my object in a file (handtest.txt) with the code:

```
h1 = Hand(3)

datafile = open('handtest.txt', 'w')

datafile.write(str(h1))

datafile.close()
```

I want to read what's in the file back and save it as another object. However, when I wrote the object in the textfile, I already changed the format as a string. How do I save it as an object again? Is it possible to do so without using pickling and json?
Here is my Hand class:

```
from card import Card
import random
"""
Defines class Hand, in file hand.py
"""

class Hand:
    """
    One object of class Hand represents a hand of cards
    and so one object stores a number of Card objects.
    """

    def __init__(self, numCardsInHand):
        """
        Initializes a Hand object with numCardsInHand Card objects inside it.
        """
        # Creates a list for storing a hand of cards.
        self.list = []
        # Creates a list for storing bj value.
        self.listBJ = []

        # Uses a loop to store a hand of cards to a list and stores the bj values of the cards to another list.
        for count in range(numCardsInHand):
           #call hitMe()
            Hand.hitMe(self)

    def bjValue(self):
        """
        Returns the blackjack value for the whole Hand of cards
        """
        BJ = ""
        # Sums up all the bj values in self.listBJ and returns it to the bjValue method.
        BJ = sum(self.listBJ)
        return BJ

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Calls the __str__( ) method and uses the returned value
        from the __str__( ) method as the string that is required.
        Returns the local variable in the string method.
        """
        # Tranforms the self.list from list type to string type and saves it as a local variable.
        all_items = '\n'.join(map(str, self.list))
        return all_items

    def hitMe(self):
        """
        Adds one randomly generated Card to the Hand.
        Randomly chooses a rank number and a suit type and save them as local variables.
        Uses the variables as the Card argument in an object. Then append the object to the self.list
        """
        # Randomly chooses a number from 1-13 and stores it as a local variable.
        all_rank = random.randint(1, 13)
        # Lists suit types.
        random_suit = ['d', 'c', 'h', 's']
        # Randomly chooses a suit type in the random_suit list and stores it as a local variable.
        all_suit = random.choice(random_suit)
        # Uses the local variables as arguments of one object of the class Card and appends the object to the self.list.
        self.list.append(Card(all_rank, all_suit))
        # Appends all_rank to self.listBJ.
        self.listBJ.append(all_rank)
```

Comment: It depends on what that object contains. Not enough information here.

Answer (score 1):

Many objects in Python have a `repr()` that corresponds to the Python code used to create it in the first place. So first change the line to use `repr` instead of `str`. (Although for some objects the `__str__` method just calls `__repr__`.)

```
datafile.write(repr(h1))
```

You can use a repr like that to reconstruct the object by using `eval()` on it. This isn't as reliable as using pickle, because some reprs are not valid Python code.

```
with open('handtest.txt') as datafile:
    h1 = eval(datafile.read())
```

Note that this is a security risk. Don't read and `eval()` the contents of files you don't trust, since malicious Python code can do bad things like deleting all your files.

Of course, this only works if the repr is valid Python code. You might have to write a proper `__repr__` method for your hand class. Also, sometimes this requires an appropriate import work. For example, if you're `eval`ing the string `'Hand(3)'`, you must have imported `Hand` for this to work.

---

Evaling the repr only works if the entire object state can be set in a single expression. Currently, your class is not designed to do that, because it randomizes things in `__init__`. So a valid repr expression, while possible, would be pretty awkward.

This need not stop you. You can create alternate initializers in Python by using `@classmethod`. Make one that can create an instance and set all of its state. Maybe something like

```
@classmethod
def of(cls, hand, bj):
    hand = super().__new__(cls)
    hand.list = hand
    hand.listBj = bj
    return hand
```

Then you could create a nice repr in terms of that.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f"Hand.of(hand={self.list!r}, bj={self.listBj!r})
```

If there's more state you want to keep, add it as another argument to the classmethod and show it in the repr.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain what should I write in the repr method in my Hand class?

Comment: @ChiaJuiHung without seeing your Hand class, no. Make it output the code to construct itself as a string. E.g. `return f'Hand({self.foo})'`, where `foo` is the appropriate attr.

Comment: I changed the code to datafile.write(repr(h1)) instead of datafile.write(str(h1)), but then the handtest won't have the output string of my Hand object.

Comment: I added my Hand class to the original post. I wrote my repr method as:
    `def __repr__(self):
        return f'Hand({self.__str__()})'. `But when I test it, it shows error in this line:h1 = eval(datafile.read()). The error is 
`File "<string>", line 1
    Hand(3 of Hearts
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
I'm sorry I'm new to python. Do you know where might be wrong in my code? Thank you so much.

Comment: I also changed repr method to return `Hand.__str__(self)` but the test error shows `print(h1.bjValue())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bjValue'`